# Connect two php files

Tags: php

As you can see, in panel.php I have href of coworkersmain.php. I want this link to be accessable only in the case when username is "admin".

This is panel.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- opens after logging in -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Panel</h1>
    <p>You are <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>.</p>  
    
    <a href="./coworkersmain.php" action="./checkadmin.php">Co-workers</a>
    <form method="post" action="./logout.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" name="logout" class="logout-button"/>
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

And this is checkadmin.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    if ($_SESSION['username'] !== 'admin') {
        // Redirect to panel page or display an error message
        echo"zdfsdgfdsfd";
        header("Location: panel.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        header("Location: coworkersmain.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have an `action` attribute on your `<a>` element?  What is that expected to do and why?  Did you just mean to use that value in the `href` attribute instead?

Comment: @David Should I use button instead?

Comment: So what's exactly wrong? Also I see no restrictions from directly accessing your `coworkersmain.php` via URL.

Comment: For what purpose?  If what you want is just an anchor link then no, you should not use a button instead of an anchor link.  If what you want is *not* an anchor link but instead what you want is a button then, yes, you'd use a button for that.  It's not really clear what you're asking.  Given the code shown and the description in the question, it just seems like a typo.  Perhaps you copied/pasted that `action` attribute from somewhere else and forgot to change it to an `href`, and forgot to replace the existing `href`?  We don't know.

Comment: @LukaBitsadze: Taking a step back... It's not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve.  Do you want to show/hide the link itself?  Do you want the link to go to a page which checks the user's login status before forwarding the user to some other page?  Do you want that other target page to not be accessible unless the user is logged in?  Something else?

Comment: Inside `coworkersmain.php` you probably want `require 'checkadmin.php';`. Then only redirect if not admin. If admin include the content you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no such thing as an `action` attribute on an `<a>` element.
2. Even if there was and it functioned like you think it would, `checkadmin.php` is functionally useless as there is nothing stopping anyone from simply going directly to `coworkersmain.php`. You need to put the access control inside the script you're actually trying to control access to.

Eg, at the top of `coworkersmain.php` use only:

```php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username'] !== 'admin') {
    header("Location: panel.php");
    exit();
}
```

Remember that the *user* controls the browser, and anything that you send to it, either HTML or Javascript, can be read, modified, or ignored entirely by the user.

If you want to enforce access control it *must* be server-side.